# Working with pointers in OpenCl kernel

Tags: c, pointers, opencl

I have the following code in OpenCl kernel:

```
char* read_data(char* data) {
    return data;
}

__kernel void some_function(__global char* source_data, __global char*  output_data) {
    char *ptr = read_data(source_data); // <--- doesn't work
    char *ptr2;
    ptr = read_data(ptr2); // <--- works
}
```

The function `read_data` doesn't work when I call it for `source_data`, and I get error -11 (CL_BUILD_PROGRAM _FAILURE) when I build it using `clBuildProgram`.
If I write

```
global char *ptr3 = source_data;
```

directly in the kernel function, it works, but stops working when I remove `global`. However, adding `global` to the `read_data` function doesn't help.

I'm using OpenCl 1.2, so it should allow working with char* (unlike 1.0).

Any idea how to make it work?

Comment: make function argument __global and name that function read_global_data. also make ptr __global

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik thank you, making ptr global helped!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I was able to solve it by making 3 things global:

1. The function `read_data`
2. The parameter of this function
3. The variable to which I assign the returned value

The following works fine:

```
global char* read_data(global char* data) {
    return data;
}

__kernel void some_function(__global char* source_data, __global char* output_data) {
    global char *ptr = read_data(source_data);
}
```